# Benchmarking Cube Processing in SSAS

Tags: sql, ssis, ssas, etl, olap-cube

I am currently working on a project to improve cube processing time. The cube currently consists of 50 facts and 160 dimensions and it takes about 4 hours to process the cube. What would be the best way to benchmark cube processing performance before embarking on troubleshooting bottlenecks. The largest dimension consists of about nine million records while the largest fact table consists of about 250 million records. How would you go about finding bottlenecks and what parameters would influence the processing time the most. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Having done a lot of SSAS processing optimization I would start with some monitoring. First setup some performance counters to monitor available memory, disk, CPU and network on the SSAS server and the database server. Some good perfmon counters (and recommendations about baselining processing performance) are in section 4.1.1 in the [SSAS performance guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn749781.aspx).

Second I would start a profiler trace connected to SSAS with the default events. Then when done processing Save As... Trace Table in profiler. Then look for the longest duration events in the SQL table you save it to. Then you know where to spend your time optimizing.

Feel free to write back with your specific longest duration events if you need help. Please also specify exactly how you are processing (like ProcessFull on the database or something else).